# Checking Response Code C#

Tags: c#, http-response-codes

I was wondering if there's a way to detect the response codes on a website using C#? Since C# .NET has HTTP-based methods, I'm assuming that it can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first link on google search reveals:

```
HttpWebResponse rep = req.GetResponse();
HttpStatusCode c = rep.StatusCode;
```

The link: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267762-retrieving-http-response-code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the HTTPWebResponse class contains a statusCode property.